# jpa when insert row should return the sequence number used for primary key column

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I know in sql(oracle) we can use "retruning into" but is there something which can be automated using JPA when using em.create().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try em.merge(), it returns the attached instance you just persisted. You might have to em.flush() before you see the generated primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i am using Abstract class to run the few methods. Am i doing right as per your suggestion to get the entity instance                                                      public Entity create(T entity) {
        //getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        Entity e =  getEntityManager().merge(entity);
       
    }

Comment: Instead of em.persist() use em.merge() so `e = getEntityManager().merge(entity);` should be all you need